# None of sequelize hooks are executing in expressJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize `6.32.0` along with express `4.18.2` and typescript. Problem is, none of the sequelize hooks are working for me. I've tried adding simple `console.log` statements but the hooks are not being called.

```
Transaction.init(
  {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    amount: {
      type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(10, 2),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    type: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM("debit", "credit"),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    user_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: User,
        key: "id",
      },
    },
    account_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: 'account',
        key: 'id'
      },
      allowNull: false
    },
    is_deleted: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: false,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    account_balance: {
      type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(15,2),
      defaultValue: 0.00,
      allowNull: false
    }
  },
  {
    tableName: "transaction",
    sequelize,
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true,
    hooks: {
      beforeValidate: () => {
        console.log("before");
      },
      beforeCreate: async (transaction, options) => {
        console.log("beforeCreate Hook");
        try {
          // Retrieve the associated account
        const account = await Account.findOne({
          where: {
            user_id: transaction.user_id,
            id: transaction.account_id,
            is_deleted: false
          }
        })

        if(account) {
          // Calculate the new balance
          let newBalance: number;

          if(transaction.type === "debit") {
            newBalance = account.balance + transaction.amount;
          }

          else {
            newBalance = account.balance - transaction.amount;
          }

          transaction.account_balance = newBalance;
  
          // Update the account balance
          await account.update({ balance: newBalance }, { transaction: options.transaction });
        }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
          console.log(options)
        }
        
  
        
      },
    },
  }
```

);

I've even tried the `addHook` method but even that is not working.

If it helps, the logic in my route for create transaction uses sequelize transactions.. so maybe that might cause the issue? I don't think that it should, though.

Please help me in solving this problem. Thanks.